# Frozen in Time Why Is This?

Tags: windows-10-mobile

What do I do? My Nokia 925 has frozen while I was reading a news article. Now I can't turn my phone off or use the return arrow.

Nothing works and I am at a loss. I can't even receive calls.

Help please

Comment: Have you tried holding the power button down for a few seconds to power it off? If not, try holding the power button *and* volume down button down for 5-10 seconds to do a soft reset.